# Tprime solution optimization

Tags: java, numbers

how to optimize this code so that the time never exceeds 2000ms 
variable input(<10^5 && >1) is the count of numbers to be checked as tprime
another nextline scans  all the numbers ranging from(>1 && <10^12).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class TprimePractise {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br = 
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line = br.readLine();
    int input = Integer.valueOf(line);
    line = br.readLine();
    long sqrt, x;
    for (String num : line.split("\\s")) {
        x = Long.valueOf(num);

        if (x == 1) {
            System.out.println("NO");
            continue;
        }
        sqrt = (long) Math.sqrt(x);
        if (sqrt * sqrt == x && isPrime(sqrt)) {
            System.out.println("YES");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO");
        }

      }
   }

   public static boolean isPrime(long num) {

    for (int j = (int) num / 2; j >= 2; j--) {
        if (num % j == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
   }
```

}

Comment: maybe a codegolf thing??

Comment: Better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/